# Merge duplicate dictionaries in a list

Tags: python-2.7

**I have this list of dictionary and I am trying to merge the duplicate dictionaries in the list**
below is the sample of the list of duplicate dictionary

```
[
            {
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "status": "Disabled",
                "notificationType": "Sms and Email",
                "escalationLevel": "High",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.373Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms and Email",
                "escalationLevel": "Low",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.554Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms",
                "escalationLevel": "Medium",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.719Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Ercy",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms",
                "escalationLevel": "Low",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-11T11:43:24.529Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Ercy",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Email",
                "escalationLevel": "Medium",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-11T11:43:24.674Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Samuel",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms",
                "escalationLevel": "Low",
                "dateCreated": "2019-12-04T11:10:09.307Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Samuel",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms",
                "escalationLevel": "High",
                "dateCreated": "2019-12-05T09:12:16.778Z"
            }
        ]
```

**I want to merge the the duplicate dictionaries keeping the value of duplicate keys and have something like this**

```
[
            {
                "userName": "Kevin",
                "status": ["Disabled","Active", "Active"]
                "notificationType": ["Sms and Email", "Sms and Email", "Sms"]
                "escalationLevel": ["High", "Low", "Medium"]
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.373Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Ercy",
                "status": "Active",
                "notificationType": "Sms and Email",
                "escalationLevel": "Low",
                "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.554Z"
            },
            {
                "userName": "Samuel",
                "status": ["Active", "Active"],
                "notificationType": ["Sms", "Sms"],
                "escalationLevel": ["Low", "High"],
                "dateCreated": "2019-12-04T11:10:09.307Z"
            },

        ]
```

anyone with a simpler way of achieving this please share your solution.

Comment: how this related to Django? How do you populate these data?

Comment: Is the second object of your output supposed to have a "userName" of "Ercy"?

Comment: Also for the second object should the status be "Active" or ["Active", "Active"]?

Comment: Shouldn't dates be grouped as well? The time-stamps differ across dictionaries.

Comment: Kent Shikama The goal is to remove duplicate dictionaries in the list but still retain the values of the  removed duplicates so I think it should be ["Active", "Active"]

Comment: What do you call a "duplicate". When the name is the same? Aren't you better off by just converting the list to a dictionary with the userName as key? [Like this](https://pastebin.com/raw/6s8wg7HT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do with `pandas`.

```
import pandas as pd

def update_dict(userName, d):
    d['userName'] = userName
    return d

In []:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
[update_dict(k, g.to_dict(orient='list')) for k, g in df.groupby(df.userName)]

Out[]:
[{'userName': 'Ercy',
  'dateCreated': ['2019-11-11T11:43:24.529Z', '2019-11-11T11:43:24.674Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['Low', 'Medium'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms', 'Email'],
  'status': ['Active', 'Active']},
 {'userName': 'Kevin',
  'dateCreated': ['2019-11-08T12:19:05.373Z', '2019-11-08T12:19:05.554Z', '2019-11-08T12:19:05.719Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['High', 'Low', 'Medium'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms and Email', 'Sms and Email', 'Sms'],
  'status': ['Disabled', 'Active', 'Active']},
 {'userName': 'Samuel',
  'dateCreated': ['2019-12-04T11:10:09.307Z', '2019-12-05T09:12:16.778Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['Low', 'High'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms', 'Sms'],
  'status': ['Active', 'Active']}]
```

In Py3.5+ you can do away with the helper function with some additional arcana:

```
[{**g.to_dict(orient='list'), **{'userName': k}} for k, g in df.groupby('userName')]
```

Answer (score 1):

This task can be reformulated in terms of converting between a long-form representation of user (`userName`) records into a wide-form one. To avoid type heterogeneity, we will lift all your dictionaries to the same type regardless of the presence of absence of duplicates, i.e.

```
userName: str,
status: List[str],
notificationType: List[str],
escalationLevel: List[str],
dateCreated: List[str]
```

Although this goes against your example, I will accumulate `dateCreated` values for the sake of consistency.

```
from itertools import groupby, imap
import operator as op


USERNAME = 'userName'


def lift_long_user_record(record):
    """
    :param record: a long-form user record
    :type record: Dict[str, str]
    """
    return {
        key: value if key == USERNAME else [value] 
        for key, value in record.iteritems()
    }


def merge_short_user_records(rec_a, rec_b):
    """
    Merge two short-form records
    """
    # make sure the keys match
    assert set(rec_a.keys()) == set(rec_b.keys())
    # make sure users match
    assert rec_a[USERNAME] == rec_b[USERNAME]
    return {
        key: rec_a[USERNAME] if key == USERNAME else rec_a[key] + rec_b[key]
        for key in set(rec_a.keys())
    }


# the data from your example
records = [
    {
        "userName": "Kevin",
        "status": "Disabled",
        "notificationType": "Sms and Email",
        "escalationLevel": "High",
        "dateCreated": "2019-11-08T12:19:05.373Z"
    },
    ...
]


groups = groupby(
    sorted(imap(lift_long_user_record, records), key=op.itemgetter(USERNAME)),
    op.itemgetter(USERNAME)
)

merged = [
    reduce(merge_short_user_records, grp) for _, grp in groups
]
```

Output

```
[{'dateCreated': ['2019-11-11T11:43:24.529Z', '2019-11-11T11:43:24.674Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['Low', 'Medium'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms', 'Email'],
  'status': ['Active', 'Active'],
  'userName': 'Ercy'},
 {'dateCreated': ['2019-11-08T12:19:05.373Z',
   '2019-11-08T12:19:05.554Z',
   '2019-11-08T12:19:05.719Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['High', 'Low', 'Medium'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms and Email', 'Sms and Email', 'Sms'],
  'status': ['Disabled', 'Active', 'Active'],
  'userName': 'Kevin'},
 {'dateCreated': ['2019-12-04T11:10:09.307Z', '2019-12-05T09:12:16.778Z'],
  'escalationLevel': ['Low', 'High'],
  'notificationType': ['Sms', 'Sms'],
  'status': ['Active', 'Active'],
  'userName': 'Samuel'}]
```